# Resizing images with GD without color loss

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to resize an image with GD and am seeing a color loss on the resized image. Here is my code:

```
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($source)); 
ImageCopyResized($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $t_width, $t_height, ImageSX($src), ImageSY($src)); 
Imagejpeg($dst, $dest, 90);
```

Comment: Possibly because you are outputting a JPEG at 90% quality? a.k.a recompression

Comment: @simshaun No, if I will set 100% quality the colors are same

Comment: Please define "color loss," or provide a side-by-side comparison of the two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using **[imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)** when declaring `$dst`?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is:

```
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
```